# Linking to a site with an answer or copying and pasting the info into the answer box?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it helpful to link to external tutorials, or will it cause long-term problems?](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/482/is-it-helpful-to-link-to-external-tutorials-or-will-it-cause-long-term-problems)

I posted a link to answer [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/27714/10527) about trailing slashes, which is to a blog from Google. They also discuss adding rel="canonical" in the blog post. IMO it's a great source for someone to read and understand how Google handles trailing slashes and from there they link to using the canonical attribute.

I posted a link instead of copying and pasting information into the answer thinking it's just a waste to re-write since I can link to the source.

In general if I have a pretty good source for an answer, is it better for the community for me to copy the answer or summarize it into the answer box and link to the source? It probably does save the asker time reading and also keeps them on the StackExchange which is good.

I see a lot of questions that are easily answered with a simple Google search, and i'm starting to think rather than linking to a source that I should begin writing out answers in more details.

This isn't a complaint or anything just wondering what most people do when they have a link to an answer like a blog post etc?